# Why can't I add this foreign key?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'll post only the main part. I have two tables, each one has to have the PK of the other as a FK.

```
CREATE TABLE apartment
(
     cod_apartment INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     cod_offer INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE offer
(
    cod_offer INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    cod_apartment INT NOT NULL
);
```

First I inserted the values on both tables and it was working, I could even search using "select * from...". But then I tried to add the foreign key:

This worked.

```
ALTER TABLE offer
ADD FOREIGN KEY (cod_apartment ) REFERENCES apartment;
```

And this not.

```html
ALTER TABLE apartment
ADD FOREIGN KEY (cod_offer) REFERENCES offer;
```

This is the error message:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__apartment__cod_offer__6383C8BA". The conflict occurred in database "kleber_apartment", table "dbo.offer", column 'cod_offer'.

The problem is, every time I try to execute, the FK name changes. And this FK actually doesn't exist. I already dropped both tables and tried to insert the values again, but the same happens.

What could be?

Comment: Is the data in the cod_offer fields of those two tables consistent with the Foreign Key constraint?

Comment: Why do you need foreign keys that go both ways?  Seems like that's going to make adding data very cumbersome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That means you're trying to add a foreign key when existing data doesn't obey that constraint. So you have a record in your `apartment` table where the `cod_offer` column does not match any value in the `cod_apartment` table.

Adding a foreign key not only constrains future data, but it requires that any existing data must also follow the rule.

And regarding the `6383C8BA`, whenever you add a constraint without giving it a name, SQL Server picks one for you. Personally, I'd recommend something like:

```
alter table dbo.apartment
add constraint FK_apartment__cod_offer
foreign key (cod_offer) references dbo.offer (cod_offer);
```

This lets you define names the way you want, and is a little more clear about what you're actually building.

Comment: I feel dumb for haven't noticed this before. The constraints were right, but I made a mistake while inserting the values in the columns of both tables. Thank you!